# Account detail page in lightning experience

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I want to display my custom account detail page in salesforce lightning.
As I am new to salesforce lightning experience, can somebody please help me to achieve this thing,also the steps to be followed?
Code for page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">    
<apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="true" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you look at the '[Build a Lightning App with the Lightning Design System](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop)' Trailhead project which walks through all the steps in detail.

Specifically, refer to the last step - '[Build the AccountList Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-6)' which builds out an Account Listing. Sample component code

```
<aura:component controller="AccountsController">
   <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
   <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
   <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">ID</span></th>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Name</span></th>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Type</span></th>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Number Of Employees</span></th>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Ticker Symbol</span></th>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Phone</span></th>
           <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Details</span></th>  
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
         <tr>
           <td>{!account.Id}</td>
           <td>{!account.Name}</td>                 
           <td>{!account.Type}</td>
           <td>{!account.NumberOfEmployees}</td>                 
           <td>{!account.TickerSymbol}</td>
           <td>{!account.Phone}</td>
           <td>
              <c:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                 label="Details"
                 svgXlinkHref="/resource/SLDS090/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account"
                 svgClass="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default"
                 onclick="{!c.showDetails}"
                 data="{!account.Id}"
              />
           </td>
         </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</aura:component>
```

Refer to the provided link for complete source code.

Answer (score 1):

There is another component **force:recordView** instead of **apex:detail** in lightning:

```
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.file.id}" type="FULL"/>
```

You can see documantation here: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm